# Creating Button Dynamically using JavaScrip

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have a task to create a number of buttons depending on the number of records found in SOQL. For now to prove that it's possible I am trying to create some test buttons. To create these buttons Dynamically I am using Javascript. On page load, I am calling a function from the Apex class in a loop.

Here is my Code on VFP:

```
<apex:page controller="Controller" action="{!LoadData}"  >
       <script type="text/javascript">
   
    
    function add(type) {
 
        alert('Hello');

  var element = document.createElement("input");
 
  element.value = type;
        element.type= 'Button';
        var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

  foo.appendChild(element);
        foo.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
          };
        
    </script>
   <div id="fooBar">Fields:</div>
<apex:outputText id="recordID" value="{!recordId}"> </apex:outputText>
            Upload Resume  
                            </button> 
      <apex:outputText value="{!add}" escape="false"></apex:outputText>


</apex:page>
```

My Apex Code:

```
public class Controller {
    public string recordId {get;set;}
    public string add {get;set;}
    Public Void LoadData()
        
    {
     
     recordId = '0014';
        
        integer count = 0; 
        do{
             add = '<script> add('+count+'); </script>';
            count++;
        } while(count <=4);
       
       
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is that I am ending up with just 1 button at the end, not 4 individual buttons. Here is what it's looking like:
[image]

NOTICE: it's taking the last count 4 from the loop and creates just one button not 4 separate. I am assuming it's something to do about calling the function from the server side, it's only calling it once at the end of the loop. If that's the case what can I do so that it loops thoguth records and creates a button for each time it loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=` is assignment; you're overwriting the previous value in each loop. Use string concatenation instead:

```
add += '<script> add('+count+'); </script>';
```